# C#, Updating a List using a delegate function as a filter

Tags: c#

I want to update a list of objects(mycapsule, has many other members) when a condition (pred) holds for one of its class members(value). Whenever I change something another thing fails, I'm newbie in C# and really confused.
Can somebody fix my code: 
In the best condition I only get get this error but I think many things are missing in my code

```
The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic ;
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static List< mycapsule<int,double> > sample=  new List< mycapsule<int,double>>();
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            sample.Add(new mycapsule<int,double> {id=1 , value= 1.2});
            update(pred, 12.3);
        }

        public static bool pred(double x)
        {
            if (x==2.5) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public class mycapsule<KT, T>
        {
            public KT id {get ; set; } 
            public T value { get ; set; }
            public int p; // and more

        }    

        public bool update(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i)
        {
            foreach (var x in sample.FindAll(item => predicate(JustValue(item))) )
            {
                x.value = i ;
            }
            return true ;
        }



        public T JustValue(mycapsule<int,T> i)
        {
            return i.value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: in update function, what is KeyRecord? Should it not be sample?

Comment: yes, you are right, I just tried to simplified it by changing names and removing unrelated codes but I missed this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't work due to type safety reasons. I corrected the code as much as possible and got this:

```
public static List<mycapsule<int, double>> sample = new List<mycapsule<int, double>>();
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sample.Add(new mycapsule<int, double> { id = 1, value = 1.2 });
    update(pred, 12.3);
}

public static bool pred(double x)
{
    if (x == 2.5) return true;
    return false;
}

public class mycapsule<KT, T>
{
    public KT id { get; set; }
    public T value { get; set; }
    public int p; // and more
}

public static bool update<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i)
{
    List<mycapsule<int, double>> list = sample.FindAll(item => predicate(JustValue(item)));
    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        x.value = i;
    }
    return true;
}

public static T JustValue<T>(mycapsule<int, T> i)
{
    return i.value;
}
```

The error is:

```
predicate(JustValue(item)) => Argument 1: cannot implicitly convert from double to T
```

This comes from the fact that you are trying to forcefully call a method that you've specified as taking a generic type `T` (`Func<T, bool>`) with a value that is known to be `double`. Although we know that `T` will be double from the call to `update(pred, 12.3);`, nothing prevents me from passing in a predicate that takes an incompatible type e.g.:

```
public static bool pred(string x)
{
    return false;
}
```

and

```
update(pred, "asdf");
```

Which is clearly inconsistent. The compiler is simply trying to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot accidentally.

To solve this, you could explicitly pass the collection to the update `method`, thus ensuring that the types are consistent:

```
public static List<mycapsule<int, double>> sample = new List<mycapsule<int, double>>();
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sample.Add(new mycapsule<int, double> { id = 1, value = 1.2 });
    update(pred, 12.5, sample);
}

public static bool pred(double x)
{
    if (x == 2.5) return true;
    return false;
}

public class mycapsule<KT, T>
{
    public KT id { get; set; }
    public T value { get; set; }
    public int p; // and more
}

public static bool update<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i, List<mycapsule<int, T>> list)
{
    foreach (var x in list.FindAll(item => predicate(JustValue(item))))
    {
        x.value = i;
    }
    return true;
}

public static T JustValue<T>(mycapsule<int, T> i)
{
    return i.value;
}
```

Comment: :S so what can we do to prevent incompatible type and solve this issue .

Comment: @user1654052: See my edit. You can add the list as a parameter to the `update` method to ensure type consistency.

Comment: Wow, great. now it seems to work, but what about performance issue :), will it actually copy the whole list or it just uses a reference to list ?

Comment: @user1654052: Only a reference is passed, so don't worry. :)

Comment: @user1654052: So it should be ok now. Did you test it?

Comment: I was able to compile it and it is great achievement. I wasn't able to compile my code since I added pred,findall to my code (1 day ago). :D Not sure if it works correctly or not but It is great progress after hours of headache .

Comment: @user1654052: Ok, please come back if you have other problems with this code. If it is ok please remember to mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Sure, I'm busy doing something, once I tried it I will come back to ask more question and Mark the answer as accepte

Answer (score 2):

Look at your update method:

```
public bool update(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i)
{
    foreach (var x in KeyRecord.FindAll(item => predicate(JustValue(item))) )
    {
        x.value = i ;
    }
    return true ;
}
```

What do you expect `T` to be here? The method is not generic (it's not written as `update<T>`) and it's not declared in a generic class.

It's *possible* that you just want:

```
public bool update<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i)
```

... but it's hard to say without knowing what `KeyRecord.FindAll` looks like. Oh, and you've got the same problem with `JustValue`.

As a side issue, the method names `update` and `pred` don't follow .NET naming conventions, and `JustValue` is a poor method name in terms of descriptiveness. `mycapsule` also doesn't follow .NET naming conventions. These things really *matter* in terms of readability.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed some classes and changed names (KeyRecord --> sample) . I will try it now :)

Comment: I changed the lines of code you asked, can you please try this one, http://pastebin.com/Zrpm0cXH

Comment: @user1654052: It's still unclear what you're trying to do. Your `update` method is generic, but your list is *always* a `List<Mycapsule<int, double>>`. *Why* do you want your predicate to be generic in the first place?

Comment: No.  Mycapsule might have different type like List<Mycapsule<int, string>>

Comment: @user1654052: But it doesn't. Not in the code you're given. You're calling `sample.FindAll`, and the type of `sample` is `List<Mycapsule<int, double>>`.

Comment: Yes, in this code it is double, but it is really need be generic so it can accept different types. I removed/changed  many lines of code for simplification, ijn the real world example "sample" is assigned when the class initialized. I know it looks crazy but it is needed to be generic

Comment: @user1654052: It's impossible to answer a question where we've only got half the context. It sounds like you should *probably* make your type generic, so that the variable can be generic as well. But basically, I can't help you further with an unrepresentative piece of sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, And for generic method the method definition you have used is not correct.
It should be

```
//MethodName<T,U>(T para1, U para2)
```

I have change the code to include reflections, this should work.
Please try and give feedback.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static List<Mycapsule<int, double>> sample = new List<Mycapsule<int, double>>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            sample.Add(new Mycapsule<int, double> { id = 1, value = 1.2 });
            update(pred, 12.3);
        }

        public static bool pred(double x)
        {
            if (x == 2.5) return true;
            return false;
        }

        public static bool update<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T i)
        {
            var myCollection = sample.FindAll(p => pred(JustValue<double>(p)));
            MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
            foreach (var x in myCollection)
            {
                MethodInfo changeTypeMethod = typeof(MainClass).GetMethod("GetValue");
                object value = changeTypeMethod.Invoke(mainClass, new object[] { i, typeof(T) });
                PropertyInfo valueProperty = x.GetType().GetProperty("value");
                valueProperty.SetValue(x, value);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public T GetValue<T>(T i)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof(T));
        }

        public static T JustValue<T>(Mycapsule<int, T> i)
        {
            return i.value;
        }
    }
    //Outside the MainClass inside the same namespace 
    public class Mycapsule<KT, T>
    {
        public KT id { get; set; }
        public T value { get; set; }
        public int p; // and more   

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You can have a class inside another class. 2) This will not compile.

Comment: This code compiles,
<br/>I might have been wrong on the class inside class, but this code compiles as long as you define KeyRecord correctly.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me: `predicate(JustValue(item)) -> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'T'`

Comment: I changed the lines of code you asked, can you please try this one, http://pastebin.com/Zrpm0cXH

Comment: the generic method call has to be JustValue<double> like i mentioned in the first post.

Comment: Vignesh It still doesn't work :( :  sample.FindAll(item => predicate(JustValue<double>(item)));

Comment: can you try out the new solution, pasted ?

Comment: No overload for method `SetValue' takes `2' arguments (CS1501)

Comment: are you including the System.Reflection namespace ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue.aspx